# what is the algorithm for updating tile position in Gridster.js

Tags: javascript, algorithm, gridview, drag-and-drop, gridster

[Gridster.js](http://gridster.net/) allows to drag and drop tiles of variable size and rearrange tiles as we drag one tile.

Does anyone know the algorithm for rearranging the tiles?

I want to make this type of grid layout in action script and I am not much familiar with Javascript, I have already tried to read the code but don't understand most of the things, so if someone can give me the algorithm I will try to implement logic using action script.

Comment: Presumably the author does. Or you could, you know, try reading [the source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/master/dist/jquery.gridster.js), linked from the page you link to...

Comment: @AakashM thanks for the reply. actually i want to make this type of grid layout in action script and i am not much familiar with java script, i have already tried to read the code but don't understand most of the things. so if some one can give me the algorithm i will try to implement logic using action script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tired a little bit more and made a grid layout as per my requirement.

here is a [demo link](http://usefulflexcomponents.blogspot.in/2015/12/blog-post.html)

i'll try to write an abstract algorithm for updating this type of tile layout,

As the time Drag is Started:

1. Calculate new drop location for the dragged item and move the drag item to the new location.
2. Check if their is any collision after moving.
3. if collision , fix the collision(i.e. move the collision tile down) go to step 2.
4. Update other tiles positions.(i.e check if any tile can be move upward if free space is available)